# Numeric Enter key not binding in Python tkinter Application in RaspberryPi Os?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, tkinter, raspberry-pi4

I have made Python Tkinter Application in RaspberryPi Os.

I am using this code this my application:
`self.root.bind('<Return>', enterp2)`

**This works with Enter Key (on alphabet side) but not works with Enter key on numeric side.**

I have tried many things but doesn't work.

Please help me to solve my issue.

Comment: Please add more code. This is very little to go on. From what I can see here you do not actually bind anything. `''` is not a bind that is valid. You have to bind to an even such as a click or mouse over or key press and so on. Next you use `self.root.bind` and that is very likely incorrect. You are more likely going to need either `self.bind()` or `root.bind()`. If you use a class to build your tkinter GUI and are actually doing `root = tk.Tk()` instead of inheriting from tk as the actually class you should consider learning class inherency.

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: @JRiggles I see what happened here. It is odd that the post was showing an empty string when you go in to edit the original post it actually shows the `<Return>`. Sorry my mistake.

Comment: @JRiggles it turns out that when using `< >` that post thinks its looking at html tags so it does not actually display what's inside of them. Since I hardly ever use `< >` and never outside of a code block I never knew this was how post worked lol. Learn something new every day.

Comment: @Mike-SMT No worries - I've had that happen to me as well! It seems like the editor escapes them properly when they're `<inside backticks>`

Answer (score 3):

The Enter key on the numpad has a different key symbol, `KP_Enter`. So just add an additional binding:

```
self.root.bind('<KP_Enter>', enterp2)
```

In the future, you can write a quick script to help you identify what keys are being pressed to solve this problem:

```
from tkinter import *

def get_key_symbol(evt):
    print("Key symbol:", evt.keysym)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
    frame.bind("<Key>", get_key_symbol)
    frame.pack()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```